# Grails search owned objects by properties

Tags: grails

I am trying to find the proper syntax for a query that I know has got to be very common but couldn't find a code example for.

```
class ObjA {
...
static hasMany = [b:ObjB]
}
```

if **a** is an instance of ObjA, I want to perform a query like:

```
a.b.findAllBsSuchThat(b.someproperty = somevalue)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid (N+1) queries for lazy associations per `a`, you can use a criteria as:

```
ObjA.withCriteria {
    b {
        eq 'someProperty', someValue
    }
}
```

or `where` queries:

```
ObjA.where { b.someProperty == somevalue }.list()
```

If you use something like `a.b.findAllBsSuchThat(b.someproperty = somevalue)` then you would be getting all `b's` for `a` and then filtering on the result. This will affect the performance and will unnecessary.

Comment: Would the syntax be slightly different if the property being tested is a `String`. This is the real test I am trying to perform `if (entRec.where { flags.color.equalsIgnoreCase('red').list() } != [])` I want to know if an `entRec` has any `flags`(Flag) whose `property color` is `red`.

Comment: `if ( entRec.where { flags.color == 'red' }.count() )` should do. `==` operator is overridden in Groovy and `count()` would result 0 if there is no match and eventually Groovy Truth would fail `if` condition.

Comment: Thanks, but just to be sure, this isn't case insensitive correct?

Comment: Correct. This is case sensitive.

Comment: @dmahaptro Not sure what do because I am getting this error.  `No such property: color for class: grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No such property: color for class: grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria
    Line | Method
->> 1085 | propertyMissing              in grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria`

Comment: I double checked that my Flag class does have a property 'color' which is a String.

Comment: I think I am starting to see my problem. Every example of criteria or query I am seeing starts with a domain class name like Person.where or Book.where. I need to know how to run the where query on an instance not a class. So, in my given example `entRec` is an instance.

Comment: Have you tried `ObjA.where { flags { color == 'red' } }.count()`. Otherwise create a small app with this problem and let me know, I can have a look at it.

Comment: Yes, it has to be the Class instead of the record instance.

Comment: But what if I don't want every ObjA that has red flags. I just want to know if a given instance of ObjA has any red flags. What kind of query would be used in a case like this? So, if `a` is an instance of `ObjA` I would want to know if `a.hasAnyFlagsWhere(flag's color is red)`. That, is what I can't quite figure out the syntax for.

Comment: Something close to this: `entRec.flags.size(color: 'red')` but I know this isn't correct.

Comment: Ok, I think I got something but not sure if it is correct. `if (entRec.flags.count {it.color == 'red'})`.